# Save/Update List of Dates in Database

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I'm looking for a creative way to save and update a list of dates in our database.

I'm going to collect a list of dates from the application and I will need to check if each value already exists, if not add, and then delete any dates not in the list that are already stored in the database.

The easiest thing I can think of is to delete all dates associated to this particular request and then iterate over each item in my list and insert into database.

Does anyone have a more elegant idea?

Comment: Use MERGE. This may help: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/08/sql-server-merge-operations-insert-update-delete-in-single-execution/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use merge.  You can also load the dates into a temporary table and do an insert such as:

```
with toinsert as (
    select thedate
    from #newdates nd left outer join
         alldates ad
         on nd.thedate = ad.thedate 
    where ad.thedate is null
)
insert into alldates(thedate)
    select thedate
    from toinsert
```

The toinsert alias uses a left outer join to do a "not in".  I often find that this works better.  Regardless of how you set up the queries (like this or with a merge), you should put in an index on the dates.  It should make things go faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of table valued parameters and the `NOT EXISTS` function. So pass your dates from your application to a stored procedure as a paramater, the stored procedure will then return a list of all the dates inserted back to your application.#

The first step is to create the type so you can pass a list of dates to your procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.DateListType AS TABLE (Date DATETIME)
```

Next create your procedure. I have assumed you date table is called `dbo.Dates`, you'll obviously need to substitute your table in for this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertDates (@Dates dbo.DateListType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Inserted TABLE (Date DATETIME)

    INSERT INTO dbo.Dates
    OUTPUT inserted.Date INTO @Inserted
    SELECT  Date
    FROM    @Dates d
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    dbo.Dates
                WHERE   Dates.Date = d.Date
            )

    SELECT  Date
    FROM    @Inserted
END
```

Not sure what your application is coded in so unfortunately can't suggest any code to call the procedure